# RSA Key Generation & encrypted output using OpenSSL

Tags: rsa, aes, openssl

When is it generally acceptable, if ever, to generate RSA keys without encrypting the PEM output with another encryption algorithm?

I am working on a CI/CD process and want to leverage asymmetric encryption, but not entirely sure whether or not it is safe to generate the RSA keys without encrypting the output. At the moment I am generating the private key and extracting the public key using the following:

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 4096
openssl rsa -in key.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out public.pem
```

I then store the content of `key.pem` in a secure place within the platform I am working in and subsequently securely delete `key.pem` from my machine. Is this generally acceptable, or should I be generating the keys using something like the following and dealing with the passphrase?

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out key.pem -passout pass:some_passphrase 4096
```

Comment: This seems to be a question of key management policy (rather than cryptography), and more suitable for [security-SE](https://security.stackexchange.com). Do you want me to migrate the question there? Please check first if they already have something similar, perhaps tagged [key-management](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/key-management) or [corporate-policy](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/corporate-policy).

Comment: @fgrieu thank you so much for the reply Looks like I found two similar posts that basically answer my questions on [security.se] and in my case if the key was compromised the password would probably be compromised as well so I think it is not entirely necessary in my particular scenario

Comment: If the question is no longer needed, it's best to close or delete it. Otherwise it could get downvoted (as a countermeasure against it popping-up periodically).

Comment: @JohnnyBass Simply said, encryption of the private key is necessary if you think that an attacker can access the private key data. You'd have to encrypt it by a key or password that is harder to access by an attacker (that has access to said private key data) for it to be more secure. If you can create a private key in a hardware device (HSM, smart card, TPM etc.) or OS-backed key store than that should definitely be considered over encryption "in software".